# Symfony 2: Disable Doctrine event listener in ContainerAwareCommand

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, command, event-listener

I am using several Doctrine listeners registered in configuration file for some automatic updates (created_on, updated_on timestamps etc.).
Currently I have implemented additional functionality that requires stashing prepared values in the database for easier searching.

I am thinking about update Symfony command that would prepare these values instead of SQL update script (actually any sort of change or update in the way the value is crated would than require just running this single command). However this would also trigger the EventListeners mentioned earlier.

Is there a way how to disable particular EventLister for single Command?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

something like this should do the trick :

```
$searchedListener = null;
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $event => $listeners) {
    foreach ($listeners as $key => $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof ListenerClassYouLookFor) {
            $searchedListener = $listener;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
if ($searchedListener) {
    $evm = $em->getEventManager();
    $evm->removeEventListener(array('onFlush'), $searchedListener);
}
else { //listener not found

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In `services.yaml` I have my listener defined this way:

```
services: 
    App\EventListener\DoctrinePostUpdateListener:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postUpdate }
```

To my listener class I added private variable `$enabled` with condition to stop execution:

```
class DoctrinePostUpdateListener
{
    private $enabled = true;    

    public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args) 
    {
        if ($this->enabled === false) { //stop execution
            return;
        }

        .. your code to execute ..

        return;
    }

    public function setEnabled(bool $enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }

}
```

and then in my `service/controller` code where I don't want to execute this listener I just set this `$enable` variable to false:

```
    $listeners = $this->em->getEventManager()->getListeners('postUpdate');
    foreach ($listeners as $key => $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof DoctrinePostUpdateListener) {
            $listener->setEnabled(false);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good idea but you should go deep and use an interface and an event to be able to simply extend this behavior to all your listener. read this https://smaine-milianni.medium.com/how-to-disable-the-listeners-in-symfony-3d30de1d6929. Then it doesn't works on third part bundle

Answer (score 2):

It make more sense to wrap the logic inside Doctrine listener around a:

`if ($this->enabled) {`

So everyone can understand that the logic can be disabled or not.

You could use a parameter to enable or not the code (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html).

```
my_doctrine_listener_enabled: true
```

You set it to false in your command:

```
$container->setParameter('my_doctrine_listener_enabled', false);
```

Since the parameter is modified at runtime, I recommend you to not use it via DIC but via

```
$container->getParameter('my_doctrine_listener_enabled')
```

Or another approach, could be:

1. Create variable "enabled" inside Doctrine listener
2. Inject Doctrine listener in command
3. Set `$this->myListener->enabled = false`

Comment: That is true. However in my original case I have needed to disable listeners which automatically updated time stamps etc. for "one-time"/repair command. Not exactly usual case

Comment: Using dependency injection did not work, but getting the service via its identifier did work (together with an `enabled` field)