# Symfony, Doctrine: how to disable Entity Listeners?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to persist some fixtures with Alice Fixtures Bundle, without triggering a specific Entity Listener.
The listener is associated with my entity through the `EntityListeners` annotation.
I'd rather not change the listener itself.

I've created a custom Loader which has access to the container, hoping to disable all listeners before creating my objects.

I've tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37961280/5845942) already, but `$em->getEventManager()->getListeners()` doesn't return Entity Listeners.

`ClassMetadata` gives me a list of subscribed Entity Listeners for that entity, but it's just a read-only array.

Is there a way of disabling those Entity Listeners?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a way.
This is what I do in my loader:

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

$entitiesWithListeners = [
    Post::class,
    Comment::class
];

$listenersToDisable = [
    MyListener::class
];

foreach ($entitiesWithListeners as $entity) {
    $metadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entity);

    foreach ($metadata->entityListeners as $event => $listeners) {
        
        foreach ($listeners as $key => $listener) {
            if (in_array($listener['class'], $listenersToDisable)) {
                unset($listeners[$key]);
            }
        }
        $metadata->entityListeners[$event] = $listeners;
    }
    $em->getMetadataFactory()->setMetadataFor($entity, $metadata);
}
```

I simply get the metadata for each entity, strip it of my Entity Listeners, and set it back to its corresponding class.

It's ugly but hey, it works.
Since I'm stuck with AliceBundle v1.4 at the moment, and I will have to change everything when we update the project, this will do.

Comment: As $metadata is an object and due to how objects are passed around this line     $em->getMetadataFactory()->setMetadataFor($entity, $metadata);
is redundant.

Thanks so much for posting this, it saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EntityListenerResolver` API

```
$em->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->clear();
```

or if you want to clear listener of specific class

```
$em->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->clear(YourEntityListener::class);
```

Refer to [EntityListenerResolver](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/EntityListenerResolver.php) interface for more info.

Comment: When I call the global `clear()` method, it seems to indeed disable some entity listeners, some of which I don't want to disable.  
But when I call it with the name of the class I want to strip of listeners, it doesn't work. The ListenersInvoker still invokes that listener from the metadata.

Comment: Of course it clears all entity listeners if you don't pass any argument, but you can pass specific class to disable. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry, I was editing my comment. Passing the class didn't work, for some reason. I'm debugging the stack, see if I understand how this works...

Comment: Actually I don't see where the EntityListenerResolver may come into play.  
For example: in UnitOfWork::persistNew(), the only thing that determines whether listeners are invoked is the ListenersInvoker, which itself seems to rely solely on the class metadata.
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/7c9ab76896661c34245e94b8521a90cfa77b2473/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L837

Comment: Ha, was about to comment about that but I see you just corrected that answer ;)
Yeah, it actually works with the name of the listener class.

Comment: Sorry I just tried it and I notice you need to pass listener class and not entity class. So either you iterate over your listeners class explicitly or over your entities and then over related listeners which you get from `$em->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($entityClass)->entityListeners`.

Comment: Wait, no, something's not right 
There's one listener still being invoked.

Comment: I'm debugging the ContainerAwareListenerResolver, and for some reason, my listener is not listed in the `instances` property, but in `serviceIds`, so the `clear()` method does not remove it.

Comment: May it be because that specific listener is declared as a lazy service?

Comment: Yep, that's it. Entity listeners tagged as "lazy" are not registered as "instances" in the ContainerAwareEnityListenerResolver and cannot be cleared that way.

Comment: Well this seems kind of a bug in my view but good to know, I was not aware of this, thank you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184402/discussion-between-victor-toulouse-and-drkey).