# Temporarly disabling a doctrine entity listener

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, listener, symfony4

I use doctrine entity listeners to send mail whenever an entity is created. I want to be able to disable this event listener when performing certain operations (fixtures are mailbombing me as soon as I try to populate my database with fake entities).

I tried to disable the listener by using the *clear* method of the **EntityListenerResolver** class without success.

Here is my listener configuration:

```yaml
services:
    mail_on_create_document_listener:
        class: App\EventListener\MailOnCreateDocumentListener
        autowire: true
        tags:
            -
                name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'
                event: 'postPersist'
                entity: 'App\Entity\Document'
```

I try to disable the listener with this code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

class DebugFixture extends Fixture implements FixtureGroupInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $manager->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver()->clear(MailOnCreateDocumentListener::class);

        dump($manager->getConfiguration()->getEntityListenerResolver());
    }
}
```

Here is the resulting dump of the EntityListenerResolver

```
^ Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\ContainerEntityListenerResolver^ {#1233
  -container: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\ServiceLocator^ {#5278
    -factory: Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::getService($registry, string $id, ?string $method, $load)^ {#283
      this: ContainerHYiq7Ex\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer {#4404 …}
    }
    -serviceMap: array:1 [
      "mail_on_create_document_listener" => array:4 [
        0 => "privates"
        1 => "mail_on_create_document_listener"
        2 => "getMailOnCreateDocumentListenerService.php"
        3 => true
      ]
    ]
    -serviceTypes: array:1 [
      "mail_on_create_document_listener" => "?"
    ]
    -externalId: null
    -container: null
    -factories: array:1 [
      "mail_on_create_document_listener" => array:4 [
        0 => "privates"
        1 => "mail_on_create_document_listener"
        2 => "getMailOnCreateDocumentListenerService.php"
        3 => true
      ]
    ]
    -loading: []
    -providedTypes: null
  }
  -instances: []
  -serviceIds: array:1 [
    "App\EventListener\MailOnCreateDocumentListener" => "mail_on_create_document_listener"
  ]
}
```

Reading the [code](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.7/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/DefaultEntityListenerResolver.php), it seems that the *clear* from **EntityListenerResolver** affects the instance part, but not the serviceIds.

How does this *clear* method is supposed to work?
Is my service declaration wrong?

EDIT: I also tried this code with no success

```php
        $evm = $manager->getEventManager();
        $listeners = $evm->getListeners("postPersist");
        while (count($listeners))
        {
            $evm->removeEventListener(array("postPersist"), array_pop($listeners));
        }
```

But I read that entity listeners were quite different from other listeners, though it was not clear which was the difference. Here is the quote from the [doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/events.html#entity-listeners):

> Different from Events an Entity Listener is invoked just to the specified entity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony 2: Disable Doctrine event listener in ContainerAwareCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37961016/symfony-2-disable-doctrine-event-listener-in-containerawarecommand)

Comment: @nico-haase
I don't really know how to apply this.
If I dump($manager->getEventManager()->getListeners()) , I only get two events registered (loadClassMetadata and postPersist) but no listener is an instance of MailOnCreateDocumentListener.

Comment: What is "this" that you want to apply? Are you sure that none of the listeners in `postPersist` are instances of your listener? Then your listener is not activated after all

Comment: Here is the content of the postPersist.
The key seems to be a hash, but there's no reference to my  MailOnCreateDocumentListener.

`"postPersist" => array:1 [
    "000000001ce5661f000000003b0dc97c" => Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Event\Listener\ORMReferenceListener^ {#355
      -referenceRepository: Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\ReferenceRepository^ {#318
        -references: []
        -identities: []
        -manager: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager^ {#338 …11}
      }
    }
  ]`

Comment: @nico-haas I've just reviewed my previous tests which I did a week ago. I had already tried the solution proposed on the answer you pointed me at. I will update my question to mention this.